# Ada, Gnat: How efficient are protected type + entry comparing to pthreads?

Tags: ada

The question is about the performance of protected type and entry using the GNAT compiler on Linux. Mutex is only used as an example (Ada does not need it).

I compared the performance of Ada Mutex implementation from Rosetta Code
(https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mutex#Ada) to a very simple C/pthread implementation called from Ada using import and C interface.

It turned out the Ada protected type + entry was 36.8x times slower.
I know that GNAT may go through its run time library and eventually ends up
calling OS primitives s.a. pthread. I excepted some overhead but not that much.

The question is: Why?

Just in case - this is my simple pthread implementation:

```ada
     -- cmutex.ads

     package CMutex is
        procedure  Lock with
            Import => True,
            Convention => C,
            External_Name => "mutex_lock";

        procedure Unlock with
            Import => True,
            Convention => C,
            External_Name => "mutex_unlock";
    end CMutex;
```

```c
    // C code
    #include <pthread.h>

    static  pthread_mutex_t mtx     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    void mutex_lock()
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    }

    void mutex_unlock()
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
```

==== EDIT ===

Adding minimal reproachable code. It is a single thread (just for test), the dummy variable is to prevent the optimizer from optimizing the entire loop out.

The test code for the pthread (cmutex) above is:

```
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;
with CMutex;
procedure test is
   dummy : Integer := 0;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100_000_000 loop
        CMutex.Lock;
        dummy := dummy + 1;
        CMutex.Unlock;
    end loop;
    Text_IO.Put_Line(Integer'image(dummy));
end test;
```

And the test code for the protected type + entry example is:

```
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;
with Ada_Mutex;
procedure test1 is
   dummy : Integer := 0;
   mtx   : Ada_Mutex.Mutex;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100_000_000 loop
        mtx.Seize;
        dummy := dummy + 1;
        mtx.Release;
    end loop;
    Text_IO.Put_Line(Integer'image(dummy));
end test1;
```

Where Ada_Mutex is a package containing the example form Rosetta code:

```
package Ada_Mutex is
protected type Mutex is
   entry Seize;
   procedure Release;
private
   Owned : Boolean := False;
end Mutex;
end Ada_mutex;
--------------------------------
package body Ada_Mutex is
   protected body Mutex is
      entry Seize when not Owned is
      begin
         Owned := True;
      end Seize;
      procedure Release is
      begin
         Owned := False;
      end Release;
   end Mutex;
end Ada_Mutex;
```

Running time of the code that using the pthread mutex is (in Intel NUC i7):

$ time ./test

```
 100000000

 real   0m0.557s
 user   0m0.553s
 sys    0m0.005s
```

And the code that uses protected type and entry:
    $ time ./test1

```
  100000000

  real  0m19.009s
  user  0m19.005s
  sys   0m0.005s
```

With no optimization (-O0) times are:

```
real    0m0.746s
user    0m0.746s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and

```
real    0m20.173s
user    0m20.172s
sys     0m0.000s
```

For pthread and protected type+entry respectively.

Note that the user time ~= real time, which means the processor 
was busy (it did not idle, or otherwise yield control)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates your finding.

Comment: It is erroneous to assume that a protected entry is only locking and unlocking shared data. The protected entry enqueues and dequeues tasks in the entry queue and contains the equivalent of a C condition variable. C mutex implementations do not support a thread queuing policy and therefore do not guarantee deterministic handling of the shared data.

Comment: as @trashgod pointed out, it would be better to provide _full_ code, production tools, versions and parameters so anyone can produce both programs on their own.

Comment: @JimRogers  I didn't know that - thank you! 
If I'm not mistaken, queuing will prevent starvation,  but to guarantee deterministic handling, we need to guarantee the queuing order.

Comment: Ada provides the ability to specify queuing policies. The default queuing policy is FIFO. All Ada compilers are required to support a FIFO queuing policy and a Priority queuing policy. In this manner the handling is deterministic. See http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-4.html for details.